# how to install Go language on windows without admin rights?

Tags: go

I don't have admin rights on my Windows machine and I am trying to install Go whose installer needs admin rights to complete the installation.

Is there any way to install Go on Windows without admin rights?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Can you download the [Windows ZIP archive](https://go.dev/dl/) and extract it to somewhere in your User folder?

You would then need to update the `GOROOT` and `PATH` environment variables accordingly.

Comment: I missed completely about the archival part. Many thanks it worked.

Comment: I can not change PATH and GOROOT without admin rights.

Comment: @Piu - If your group policies are blocking you from setting user level environment variables you can create a batch file or ps1 file to temporarily (for the session) set goroot.

Comment: @Piu Sorry just realized - you can also setup your powershell profile and set the two env var's needed. This doesn't help CMD but it will definitely work.

Comment: For those who couldnt modify environment variables from non-admin accounts - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/931715/you-cannot-modify-user-environment-variables-in-the-system-properties

Comment: You can use this powershell command to set the user environment variable without opening the UI. the article linked by @Nilesh still asks you to enter admin password.
`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH',"$([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH','user')); $ENV:LocalAppData\Local\Programs\go\bin",'user')`

Answer (score 3):

The question is still relevant and the preceding answer is still correct, but the link should be updated to https://go.dev/dl/ to obtain a Windows zip archive and not the msi installer.

It is also worth noting that environment variables may be found and edited by using the search bar to find "Edit the system environment variables" in the control panel.